# How to handle dynamically created UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIViewController that acts as a sort of menu.  The menu is made up of multiple boxes/tiles which are UIViews that contain a UILabel with a description, a UIButton that links to another UIViewController that shows more information and another UIButton that links to the UIViewController that show another area of the app.

At the moment there are 3 of these boxes but this will grow.  At the moment I have hardcoded each one like this:

```
- (void)drawProceduresBox
{
self.viewProceduresBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.05), (_screenHeight * 0.35), (_screenWidth * 0.9), (_screenHeight * 0.25))];
[_viewProceduresBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
_viewProceduresBox.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
_viewProceduresBox.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

CGFloat boxHeight = _viewProceduresBox.frame.size.height;
CGFloat boxWidth = _viewProceduresBox.frame.size.width;

self.buttonShowProcedures = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[_buttonShowProcedures setFrame:CGRectMake((boxWidth * 0.8), (boxHeight * 0.4), (boxWidth * 0.1), (boxHeight * 0.2))];
[_buttonShowProcedures setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[_buttonShowProcedures addTarget:self action:@selector(showProcedures) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

_buttonshowMoreInfo = [[appButton alloc] init];
[_buttonshowMoreInfo setFrame:CGRectMake((boxWidth * 0.6), (boxHeight * 0.6), (boxWidth * 0.1), (boxHeight * 0.2))];
[_buttonshowMoreInfo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[_buttonshowMoreInfo setWhatToShow:@"vetMed"];
[_buttonshowMoreInfo addTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_viewProceduresBox addSubview:_buttonShowProcedures];
```

}

There could be 10+ of these boxes so I wanted a way to create them dynamically.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
-(void)drawBox:(NSString*)moduleName boxFrame:(CGRect)boxFrame labelDesc:(NSString*)labelDesc
{

UIView *moduleInfoBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:boxFrame];
[moduleInfoBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

CGFloat boxHeight = moduleInfoBox.frame.size.height;
CGFloat boxWidth = moduleInfoBox.frame.size.width;

UILabel *moduleLable = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[moduleLable setFrame:CGRectMake((boxWidth * 0.05), (boxHeight * 0.05), (boxWidth * 0.6), (boxHeight * 0.9))];
[moduleLable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[moduleLable setText:labelDesc];

UIButton *showModuleButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[showModuleButton setFrame:CGRectMake((boxWidth * 0.8), (boxHeight * 0.15), (boxWidth * 0.1), (boxWidth * 0.2))];
[showModuleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[showModuleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showModule:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *showMoreInfoButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[showMoreInfoButton setFrame:CGRectMake((boxWidth * 0.8), (boxHeight * 0.65), (boxWidth * 0.1), (boxWidth * 0.1))];
[showMoreInfoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[showMoreInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[moduleInfoBox addSubview:moduleLable];
[moduleInfoBox addSubview:showModuleButton];
[moduleInfoBox addSubview:showMoreInfoButton];

_scrollHeight = _scrollHeight + (moduleInfoBox.frame.origin.y + moduleInfoBox.frame.size.height);

[_scrollView addSubview:moduleInfoBox];


}
```

And I would call the method like this (for three boxes in this case):

```
CGRect formularyFrame = CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.05), (_screenHeight * 0.05), (_screenWidth * 0.9), (_screenHeight * 0.25));
CGRect proceduresFrame = CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.05), (_screenHeight * 0.35), (_screenWidth * 0.9), (_screenHeight * 0.25));
CGRect vetMedFrame = CGRectMake((_screenWidth * 0.05), (_screenHeight * 0.65), (_screenWidth * 0.9), (_screenHeight * 0.25));
[self drawBox:@"Formulary" boxFrame:formularyFrame labelDesc:@"Desc about formulary module"];
[self drawBox:@"Procedures" boxFrame:proceduresFrame labelDesc:@"Desc about procedures module"];
[self drawBox:@"VetMed" boxFrame:vetMedFrame labelDesc:@"Desc about vetMed module"];
```

The problem I am having is that the dynamically generated UIButtons need to link to relevant things, UIViewControllers in this case.  The buttons each have a selector that fires the methods 'showModule' and 'showModuleInfo'.

In these methods, how do I tell what UIButton was pressed, and therefor, know which UIViewController to push the navigationController to?  Basically I would like something along the lines of:

```
-(void)showModule:(NSString*)moduleToShow
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moduleToShow animated:NO];
}
```

But as I understand it, you cannot add parameters to '@selector' assignment:

```
[_buttonshowMoreInfo addTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: Well, create them dynamically. Go through a loop if you want. Hold them in an array when you don't know how many there could be. Or use a table and add the buttons to a cell. Or don't hold them at all in any local variable but assign them a tag. You can use the tag, once the button is clicked to identify which button was clicked - if you need to know.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve in the end.  I will have a loop that goes through an array of module names that are stored in an SQLite DB and then build each box with relevant links to dynamically created UIViewControllers.  I just don't know how to tie up the dynamically created UIButtons with the method that loads the dynamically created UIVCs.

Comment: Somehow you will have to know which view controller is to be called for each of the buttons. If you can do that using an integer as id, let's say an index of an array. Then use a for loop to create the views with `i` as loop variable. Assign `i` to the `tag` property of each button. When the button is pressed then an action is called to which the `sender` is handed over. The sender is an `UIView` subclass which is the very button that has been pressed. Fetch its `tag` value and go from there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a mapping between a button and a view controller class to show on button tap, you have 2 easy options:

1. Assign a tag to each button and create a dictionary that maps tags to classes (to either an `NSString` or a `Class`):

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *tagClassDic;

   -(void)drawBox:(NSString*)moduleName boxFrame:(CGRect)boxFrame labelDesc:(NSString*)labelDesc buttonTag:(NSInteger)tag {
       ...
       showModuleButton.tag = tag;
   }

   -(void)showModule:(UIButton *)sender {
       NSString *classStr = self.tagClassDic[@(sender.tag)];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:[NSClassFromString(classStr) new] animated:NO];
       // or, if you decide to store classes in the dictionary:
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.tagClassDic[@(sender.tag)] new] animated:NO];
   }

   ...

   self.tagClassDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

   NSInteger firstTag = 1;
   [self drawBox:@"Formulary" boxFrame:formularyFrame labelDesc:@"Desc about formulary module" buttonTag:firstTag];
   self.tagClassDic[@(firstTag)] = @"ViewController"; // or [ViewController class]
   ```
2. Set associated object (again, a string or a class) directly to the button object:

   ```
   static const char *kViewControllerClassKey = "viewControllerClassKey";

   -(void)drawBox:(NSString*)moduleName boxFrame:(CGRect)boxFrame labelDesc:(NSString*)labelDesc viewControllerClassStr:(NSString*)classStr {
       ...
       objc_setAssociatedObject(showModuleButton, kViewControllerClassKey, classStr, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
   }

   -(void)showModule:(UIButton *)sender {
       NSString *classStr = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, kViewControllerClassKey);
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:[NSClassFromString(classStr) new] animated:NO];
   }

   ...

   [self drawBox:@"Formulary" boxFrame:formularyFrame labelDesc:@"Desc about formulary module" viewControllerClassStr:@"ViewController"];
   ```

Comment: The second option there seems to make sense and could be exactly what I need.  I would prefer not using tags as the method that generates the UIButtons makes 2 different buttons per 'run'.  Also with tags I would need some sort of lookup?  tag 1 = catsVC, tag 2 = dogsVC.. etc.

Comment: lookup is done via dictionary in the first option: key is button's tag and value is the class.

Comment: Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted at the time but this is effectively what solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little off on the method that is called when you tap on your `UIButton`. For instance, right now you have:

```
// if a button action triggers this as your code is written, it won't have a valid string.
-(void)showModule:(NSString*)moduleToShow
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moduleToShow animated:NO];
}
```

This implies that the `showModule:` method will receive an `NSString` object when you tap on the button, but in actuality it will receive the `UIButton` object that triggered the event. Something like this:

```
-(void)showModule:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // use information about the button that sent the action
}
```

A common approach to knowing which button was tapped is to set a unique tag on your buttons when you create them. If you just have a few, coding an `int` onto them would work fine- if you have many and need to distinguish them all, you may want to set up macros so that you can name your `int`s.

```
UIButton *showModuleButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
...
showModuleButton.tag = 1;
[showModuleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showModule:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now, whenever you "touch up inside" of your button, `showModule:` will be called, and in it you can access the `tag` property of the `sender` to see which button triggered the event.

```
-(void)showModule:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // use information about the button that sent the action
    if(sender.tag == 1)
    {
        // you know which button triggered the event now!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the example I posted at the end is more of a 'I would like it like this' rather than what I had used.  I had a try using tags but how would I assign the tags?  As at the moment the same code is used to created each UIButton.  Also the method that creates the button creates two buttons, not one.

Comment: @Ryan So you're saying you have 2 buttons that are created in identical ways, but you want them to have different actions?

Comment: Each UIView that is added has 1 UILabel and 2 UIButtons.

Comment: It's not the cleanest option, but you could pass a `BOOL` or something like that to your view creation method (false for one view, true for the other) and based off that value change the tags when you create them (pseudocode: `if(true) tag=1; else tag=47;`)

Comment: This is the kind of 'work around' I was heading towards but wondered what the 'correct approach' was to dynamically creating an unknown number of UIButtons that each do something slightly different.

Comment: If you want to use the same code to create different buttons, you're going to need to send more parameters to the method that creates the buttons. Another option that would support more views would be to pass in an `int` (instead of BOOL) and multiply your tags by that passed value. For instance, pass in 0 for first, 1 second, etc and then `button.tag = (passedInt * 10) + 1` to get 1 for first view, 11 for second, 21 for third, etc.